# Delphi XE7 canvas stretchdraw in a thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, draw

I have a multi-threaded app, in the thread class there is an FInputImage: VCL.Graphics.TBitmap. I have another image called FImageV: VCL.Graphics.Bitmap.

Check the following code:

```
  ...
  FImageV.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'IMAGEH');
  ...

  FInputImage.Canvas.Lock;
  try
    FInputImage.Canvas.CopyMode := cmSrcCopy;
    FInputImage.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
    FInputImage.Canvas.Rectangle(SR);
    FInputImage.Canvas.StretchDraw(SR, FImageV);
  finally
    FInputImage.Canvas.Unlock;
  end;
```

If I submit more images so more than one thread is running, after a while the StretchDraw does nothing, it disappears. I just see the red rectangle drawn with Rectangle(SR).

This happens randomly. All objects are created and freed inside the thread. I also tried to add the FImageH as a separate class variable, since it is a static image, but the results are the same.

Any ideas why this is happening would be welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lock the canvas of `FImageV` too.